# KeyError: 'data'. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, api, roblox

I am currently attempting to create a program that notifies me to a discord channel with a discord webhook whenever I get a new chat message on Roblox with the contents of the chat message to a discord channel. here is the code I currently have right now:

```
import requests
import json

cookie = "__"

webhook_url = "__"

conversations_response = requests.get(
    "https://chat.roblox.com/v2/get-user-conversations?pageNumber=1&pageSize=30",
    headers={"Cookie": cookie}
)

unread_conversations = [
    conversation for conversation in conversations_response.json()['data']
    if conversation["hasUnreadMessages"]
]

for conversation in unread_conversations:
    messages_response = requests.get(
        f"https://chat.roblox.com/v2/get-conversation-messages?conversationId={conversation['id']}&pageSize=50",
        headers={"Cookie": cookie}
    )

    latest_message = messages_response.json()['data'][-1]

    message_contents = latest_message["content"]

    discord_message = {
        "embeds": [{
            "title": f"New message from {conversation['title']}",
            "description": message_contents
        }]
    }

    requests.post(webhook_url, json=discord_message)
```

I ran this code on my command prompt and received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Desktop\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    conversation for conversation in conversations_response.json()['data']
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'data'
```

If you have any idea about how I can fix this, or any other bugs you may have noticed are present in my code, please let me know. thanks!

Comment: Why are you expecting a `'data'` key? You can read the response models in the swager docs [here](https://chat.roblox.com/docs/index.html). I can't see any `'data'` in the response model for `/v2/get-user-conversations`.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError` means that there is no key named like the one you provided. So the JSON has no key `data`. You have to check the `API` or try to figure it out by your experiments. I suggest you print the JSON result (print the whole dictionary by `print(conversations_response.json())` or just print the its keys by `print(conversations_response.json().keys())`) and see what the data looks like. Then update the key to what you want and the code will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`conversations_response.json()` already contains the conversations. There's no `data` field. Replace `conversations_response.json()['data']` with `conversations_response.json()`

Comment: ok so I did this, and I appear to be receiving another error message:
  File "Desktop\test.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    if conversation["hasUnreadMessages"]
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: Again, if you print `conversation` you notice that it's a string, not a dictionary. try using `json.loads(conversation)['hasUnreadMessages']`

Answer (score 0):

Because your response.json() has no data field,
check your request and send Authorization in request header.

```
requests.get('<URI>', headers={'Authorization': '<TOKEN>'})
```

This URI that you used, need to authorized.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json

cookie = "__"
webhook_url = "__"
req = requests.Session()
req.cookies['.ROBLOSECURITY'] = cookie

conversations_response = req.get(
"https://chat.roblox.com/v2/get-user-conversations?pageNumber=1&pageSize=30"
)
print(conversations_response.json())
```

While I don't understand what you are trying to do this is the answer to your problem.

Comment: ...if you don't understand what OP is trying to do, how can you know that this snippet solves the problem?